# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I want to update a record :

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query;

class Client extends Model {
    function modifierClient($tab) {

        $setColumns = "";
        $separateur = "";

        foreach ($tab as $k => $v){
          if ($k == 'clt_id')
            continue;
          $setColumns .= $separateur . 'c.' . $k . " = '" . $v . "'";
          $separateur = ",";
        }

        $sSQL = "UPDATE client c SET $setColumns WHERE c.clt_id = '".$tab['clt_id']."'";

        $query = new Query($sSQL, $this->getDI());
        $ret = $query->execute();

    }
}
```

the `$tab` array has these indexes :

```
Array
(
    [clt_id] => 7
    [clt_cin_pass] => aaaaa
    [clt_nom] => aaaaaaaaa
    [clt_prenom] => aaaaaaaaaa
    [clt_tel] => aaaaaaaa
    [clt_adresse] => aaaaaaaa
    [clt_comment] => aaaaaaaaaayy
)
```

At runtime I got this error : `Exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'client.clt_id' in 'field list'`

So what is wrong ?

**UPDATE**

here is table structure from phpMyAdmin :

[image]

Comment: There's no `clt_id` column in your table.

Comment: there is ! I use phpMyAdmin and the column is there !

Comment: Post table structure for your table `client`

Comment: Should you really be trying to update `client.clt_id` I assume its a primary key, try leaving that column out of the `$setColumns` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : I prefixed each column in the `SET` clause and in the `WHERE` with the table name !

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$sSQL = "UPDATE client c SET ".$setColumns." WHERE clt_id = '".$tab['clt_id']."'";
```

Comment: And what's the difference from the posted query?

Comment: @Rahul Difference of $setcolumns variable

Comment: it gives same problem !

Comment: `UPDATE client SET clt_cin_pass = 'aaaaa',clt_nom = 'aaaaaaaaa',clt_prenom = 'aaaaaaaaaa',clt_tel = 'aaaaaaaa',clt_adresse = 'aaaaaaaa',clt_comment = 'aaaaaaaaaa' WHERE clt_id = '7'`

Comment: Check you database connection and table design definition. It is not problem here...